# How can a formula have nontrivial alternation number?

Tags: model-theory

I'm trying to understand the basic properties of indiscernible sequences, and it seems like I'm not understanding the definition correctly, because it seems like the alternation number of a formula should be trivial by the definition of indiscernible sequences.

### Background

Conventions:
$\phi(x;y)$ denotes a "partitioned" formula: w/ *variables $x$* and *parameters $y$*

The definition of indiscernible sequence from "A Guide to NIP Theories":

> We will typically denote sequences of tuples by $I = (a_i : i \in \mathcal{J})$ where $\mathcal{J}$ is some linearly-ordered set. The order on $\mathcal{J}$ [is] $<_{\mathcal{J}}$ [...]
>
> Let $\Delta$ be a finite set of formulas and $A$ a set of parameters. A (possibly finite) sequence $I = (a_i : i \in \mathcal{J})$ is $\Delta$-indiscernible over $A$, if for every integer $k$ and two increasing tuples $i_1 <_{\mathcal{J}} ... <_{\mathcal{J}} i_k$ and $j_1 <_{\mathcal{J}} ... <_{\mathcal{J}} j_k$, $b \in A$ and formula $\phi(x_1, ..., x_k ; y) \in \Delta,$ we have $\phi(a_{i_1}, ..., a_{i_k} ; b) \leftrightarrow \phi(a_{j_1}, ..., a_{j_k} ; b).$ An **indiscernible sequence** is an *infinite* sequence which is $\Delta$-indiscernible for all $\Delta$.

So I interpret an **indiscernible sequence** to mean:

For $\mathcal{J}$ a linearly-ordered set,

$I = (a_i | i : J)$
Indiscernible over a set of parameters $A$

$:\iff$

$\forall \phi(x_1, ..., x_k; y) : \text{Partitioned Formula in L}, k : \mathbb{N}, (i), (j) : k-\operatorname{Chain}(\mathcal{J}), b : A,$

$\phi(a_{i_1}, ..., a_{i_k}; b) \leftrightarrow \phi(a_{j_1}, ..., a_{j_k}; b),$

where by $L$ I mean the ambient language $L$ for the formulas.

The definition of **alternation number of a formula** $\phi$ from "Introduction to theories without the independence property":

> $\operatorname{alt}(\phi(\bar{x}; \bar{y})) = \max \big\{ n < \omega \; \big| \; \exists (\bar{a}_i)_{i < \omega} \; \textit{indiscernible} \; \exists \bar{b} \; \forall i < n - 1 \; \big[ \models \phi(\bar{a}_i; \bar{b}) \leftrightarrow \neg \phi(\bar{a}_{i+1}; \bar{b}) \big] \big\}$
>
> if the maximum exists, or $\infty$ otherwise

That is, it's the maximum over indiscernible sequences of the **number of alternations of the formula** $\phi$ **on the sequence**.

(And "Introduction to theories without the independence property" says "the alternation number of $\phi(\bar{x}; \bar{y})$ counds the maximal number of segments into which an instance $\phi(\bar{x}; \bar{b})$ of $\phi$ can cut an indiscernible sequence")

### Problem

The point of indiscernibility seems to be you can't use any formula in $L$ to distinguish two subsequences of the same length against the same element of the parameter set. Thus, intuitively, it shouldn't be possible to make the formula alternate on the sequence. And we have:

**Prop)** *Let $I = (a_i | i : \mathcal{J})$ indiscernible over $A$,*

$2 \leq  n : \mathbb{N},$

$i : n-\operatorname{Chain}(\mathcal{J}),$

$b : A,$

$\phi(x_1; y) : \text{Partitioned Formula in L in one variable}$.

*Then*
*$\forall (t < u : n), \phi(a_{i_t}; b) \leftrightarrow \phi(a_{i_u}; b).$*

**Proof:**

If $t, u : n$, then $(i_t), (u_t) : 1-\operatorname{Chain}{\mathcal{J}}$.

But $I$ indiscernible over $A$, hence in the special case $k=1$,

$\forall \tilde\phi(x_1; y) : \text{Partitioned Formula in L}, (\tilde i), (\tilde j) : 1-\operatorname{Chain}(\mathcal{J}), b : A,$

$\tilde\phi(a_{\tilde i_1}; b) \leftrightarrow \tilde\phi(a_{\tilde j_1}; b).$

Thus, in the special cases $\tilde\phi = \phi$, $(\tilde i) = (i_t)$, $(\tilde j) = (i_u)$,

$\phi(a_{i_t}; b) \leftrightarrow \phi(a_{i_u}; b).$

**Corrollary)** *The alternating number of every single-variable formula in $L$ is 1.*

i.e., for every $I = (a_i | i : \mathcal{J})$ indiscernible over $A$, $( \phi(a_{i_1}; b) \leftrightarrow \neg \phi(a_{i_2}; b) ) \rightarrow ( \phi(a_{i_2}; b) \leftrightarrow \phi(a_{i_1}; b) \leftrightarrow \neg \phi(a_{i_2}; b) )$.

### Nontrivial examples

In "Introduction to theories without the independence property," two examples are given, but no proof. I can't then see how the limit is attained and thus distinguish what allows a formula to alternate on an indiscernible sequence:

> For example, the alternation number of a formula with constant truth value, like $x = x \wedge y = y,$ is 1, the alternation number of a linear order is 2, and $\operatorname{alt}(x = y) = 3.$

I would expect these are to be implemented as formulas in one parameter (y) and one variable (x), like the [divisibility example for the independence property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NIP_(model_theory)#Examples).

### Refs

P. Simon, *A Guide to NIP Theories*.

H. Adler, *Introduction to theories without the independence property*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\overline{a}$s are being distinguished by the tuple $\overline{b}$, but $\overline{b}$ is *not* required to be a tuple from the parameter set over which the $\overline{a}$s are indiscernible.

So, for example, consider:

- The structure is $(\mathbb{Q}, <)$ and our parameter set is $A=\emptyset$.
- Our indiscernible sequence is $a_i=i$ - the natural numbers. It's easy to see that this is in fact an $A$-indiscernible sequence.
- $b={1\over 2}$.
- $\varphi(x;y)$ is "$x<y$."

Then we have $\varphi(a_0; b)$ but $\neg\varphi(a_1; b)$; this shows that the alternating number of "$x<y$" is at least $2$. And it's easy to see that in fact it has to be exactly $2$, since the indiscernible sequence has to be monotone.

In particular, note that while the sequence of $a_i$s above is indiscernible over $\emptyset$

Comment: No structures are being used, and "A Guide to NIP theories" mentions *b* ranges over the monster model $\mathcal{U}$ in the def of 'alt'. So does this mean the definitions of these texts are relative to the monster model? That would mean the examples are to be taken relative to these structures, rather than $\mathbb{Q}$ or like. Which sounds frightening, but I'll try it. Parameters are subsets of the monster model in "Guide", so it's subsets of the structure that you take parameters in; $A$ must be a set of rationals in your example?

Comment: @runKleisli "No structures are being used, and "A Guide to NIP theories" mentions b ranges over the monster model  in the def of 'alt'." That was an oversight on my part, I should have picked a monster model for DLO, but it doesn't affect the main point. "Parameters are subsets of the monster model in "Guide", so it's subsets of the structure that you take parameters in; A must be a set of rationals in your example?" This is missing the point. The point is that a sequence is indiscernible *over some set of parameters* and this set is *not* the whole ambient model (monster model in this case).

Comment: Taking a simple example: do you see why the natural numbers with their usual order form an $\emptyset$-indiscernible sequence in $(\mathbb{Q}, <)$ but not an $\{17\}$-indiscernible sequence in $(\mathbb{Q}, <)$?

Comment: What I'm asking is, do the rationals in your example replace the monster model, and must the parameters be a subset of the ground structure, be that monster or specific model?

Comment: I can understand that potentially every infinite sequence of distinct rationals is an $\emptyset$-indiscernible sequence as long as we're saying the sequences like $I$ are of elements of the ambient model, w/c could be $(\mathbb{Q}, <)$ or could be the monster model, while the sequences (2/3) and (17) can be distinguished by the partially instantiated formula $\phi(x;17) = x < 17$.

Comment: @runKleisli "What I'm asking is, do the rationals in your example replace the monster model, and must the parameters be a subset of the ground structure, be that monster or specific model?" Yes. In general, we can talk about an indiscernible sequence in an arbitrary model $\mathcal{M}$, over parameters from that model.

Comment: The point is that in this question, you have a sequence which is indiscernible *over $A$* and you're distinguishing between its elements via some tuple $\overline{b}$; this is totally possible if $\overline{b}\not\in A$.